# Why sharepoint not working with Safari browser?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010, safari, sharepoint-clientobject

I am developing silverlight web part using client object model for sharepoint 2010. My web part is working properly on IE but it is not working in Safari. I have windows 7 OS and safari 5.1.2 browser. I found that ExecuteQueryAsync() is not working properly in safari. I have the following statement

```
clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(HandleManagerUserGroupRequestSucceeded, HandleManagerUserGroupRequestFailed);
```

After executing this statement, control neither goes into the success event handler HandleManagerUserGroupRequestSucceeded nor goes into the failed event handler HandleManagerUserGroupRequestFailed. At the same time it is also not giving any exception. Can you please tell me why this is happening ? Is there any way resolve the above problem ? Please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported with limitations on non-Windows operating systems for Safari 4.04

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

Comment: yes I know that. But the above problem is the cuase of same limitation ?

Comment: I think, you didn't understand the sentence written above, it says 4.04 version is supported; so yours 5.1.2 is not supported. Please try your code in that specific browser version, and if the problem continues then you should ask about the known limitation. The link includes the known limitations for safari also, but there doesn't seem to be a client-side known limitation.